# Getting syntax error while upgrading to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade

Hi I am getting the below error while upgrading Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.4

> MiBsyntax error, unexpected token "", expecting variable#0
> /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322):
> Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/html/v...'

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue so I tracked it back to below class and added a echo statement. The last class shown in the output was having a extra comma in the constructor.

> Class /vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php Line 428

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue , It was in my extension where there was space after \ in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is new line after `ResourceModel\`  in the following path

```
/app/code/Company/MpVendorRegistration/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php
```

the code was like bellow

```
use Company\MpVendorRegistration\Model\ResourceModel\
        VendorRegistrationAssignGroup\CollectionFactory as VendorRegistrationAssignGroupCollection;
use Company\MpVendorRegistration\Model\ResourceModel\
        VendorRegistrationAttribute\CollectionFactory as VendorRegistrationAttributeCollection;
```

It must be like bellow code

```
use Company\MpVendorRegistration\Model\ResourceModel\VendorRegistrationAssignGroup\CollectionFactory as VendorRegistrationAssignGroupCollection;
use Company\MpVendorRegistration\Model\ResourceModel\VendorRegistrationAttribute\CollectionFactory as VendorRegistrationAttributeCollection;
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this error in my custom extension when ; (semicolon) was missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to run command using php version like:**

```
/usr/bin/php8.1 bin/magento setup:di: compile
```

Instead of `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`